# Face Mask for Shmoneh Esreh?

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick

Is a facemask considered "overdressed for davening"? Is there a difference between a disposable blue one vs custom made

Comment: Is there an issur to be overdressed. What is an issur is to be 'badly' dressed like almost everyone wearing t'fillin, with one hand in and one out of the jacket. One doesnt stand before a king like that.

Comment: I hope the options you're considering are davening in a minyan with a mask or davening by yourself without a mask.  Because davening in a minyan without a mask is obviously asur.

Answer (score 5):

The mishna brura gives a general guideline of how ones attire should be when davening [90:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.91?lang=he)

Specifically that one should see themselves standing in front of a king and with awe and dress accordingly.

These days, due to the pandemic, it is perfectly normal to visit the president of the U.S. or the prime minister of Israel with a mask and probably it is enforced.

No reason to assume that it's not appropriate to daven with one on.

What's more, there are those who will consider a person who davens in shul without a mask as a rodef (רודף).

Comment: Does anyone _not_ consider such a person a rodef?

Comment: The Rodef argument doesn't help because he can just daven alone.

Comment: Double AA, use commend sense. The whole assumption of the question is that one is not davening alone as there is no need for the mask and no one in the right mind would speak with the president or a king with a mask on their face for no purpose. And if one must daven alone in an area which one suspects has the virus droplets still in the air, then once again the mask is needed. The last sentence of the answer was to prevent someone from suggesting to daven in a shul without a mask.

Comment: @Heshy The danger is sufficiently attenuated that to use the the term Rodef seems ridiculous. I am aware of Poskim who suggest standing at a significant distance and prohibit a mask during Sh"E. If Prime Ministers compromise on their honor due to health risk, does this make the garment honorable?

Comment: Every location has to be judged according to local circumstances. But even in an area with an outbreak r"l, an individual is most likely not infected. Therefore he will be at worst "safek rodef", which many poskim do not consider rodef. And even if he is a carrier, he will not necessarily infect anyone at minyan without mask, especially if he is careful to maintain distancing. And if someone at the minyan  becomes infected he may well become better, though of course, he might infect others while he is contagious.